# Apache shiro and JSESSIONID

Tags: java, apache, shiro

I'm testing out apache shiro and just built the simple demo located at https://github.com/pires/simple-shiro-web-app

This is just a simple usage of shiro where it tries to authenticate with jdbcrealm. Every thing works fine except

- Shiro does not change the SESSIONID after a successful
  authentication. This means the SESSIONID is same when the user
  arrives at the login page and also once the user is authenticated.
- Also noted that after successfully authenticated if I close the
  browser, the next time I open and navigate to the page, I need to log
  in again.

Is this the usual behaviour of shiro. If yes why?

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, shiro does not generate a new ID upon user login. You could easily implement this yourself though:

```
@Override
protected boolean executeLogin( final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response )
        throws Exception
{
    final AuthenticationToken token = createToken( request, response );
    if ( token == null )
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Your error message here" );
    }
    try
    {
        // Stop session fixation issues.
        // https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-170
        final Subject subject = getSubject( request, response );
        Session session = subject.getSession();
        // Store the attributes so we can copy them to the new session after auth.
        final LinkedHashMap<Object, Object> attributes = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
        final Collection<Object> keys = session.getAttributeKeys();
        for ( Object key : keys )
        {
            final Object value = session.getAttribute( key );
            if ( value != null )
            {
                attributes.put( key, value );
            }
        }
        session.stop();
        subject.login( token );
        // Restore the attributes. 
        session = subject.getSession();
        for ( final Object key : attributes.keySet() )
        {
            session.setAttribute( key, attributes.get( key ) );
        }
        return onLoginSuccess( token, subject, request, response );
    }
    catch ( AuthenticationException e )
    {
        return onLoginFailure( token, e, request, response );
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-170#commentauthor_14621864_verbose)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK shiro does not change the session id when a login occurs. I did use it on my project and saw no sign that it does change the session id. I think it is simply a feature they don't support. When I switched to spring I had all sorts of problems because spring does support this behaviour.

As for your second point I would assume it has something to do with the longevity of the session. That session is probably configured to only last until the browser closes. If Shiro is using url rewriting to maintain the session it would have to request another login as the session id suffix on the url would be lost. With cookie's this behaviour can be supported although the typical way to do this is to use a remember-me cookie.

Comment: Well I'm curious whether we have an option in shiro to keep a cookie to identify a user session until it time out at the server side. In that case changing the sessionid on authenticating is needed as to avoid any session fixation attacks. As a side note the remember me function in shiro is not giving what I'm expecting.

Comment: it's been requested ;) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-170
Having migrated to spring security I did find spring security to have a few extra security features over shiro.